# How to Change a Windows Azure subcription Service Administrator?

Tags: azure

I can add and remove a co-administrator, but what about the service administrator?

Mainly I want to change the service administrator to another Live ID.

Note that I am using a Windows Azure Pass (i.e. 40 days free service).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't a programming question; it's a service management function.

Comment: Its like a 4 years old question.

Comment: The nomenclature "service administrator" is no longer used. It's a "classic subscription administrator role" as explained here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/billing/billing-add-change-azure-subscription-administrator

Comment: @MattKocaj the name "Classic Subscription Administrator Roles" groups three types of administrator roles but each role has different permissions. It's important in this case to refer to this role by its name "Service Administrator" because it's not the same to change this account vs changing the Co-Administrator Account ([Classic subscription administrator roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/rbac-and-directory-admin-roles#classic-subscription-administrator-roles))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same question (ish): I wanted to change the service administrator for a subscription, but I am not using the 40 days free pass.

[The blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/patrick_butler_monterde/archive/2010/02/10/windows-azure-billing-overview.aspx) that OperatorOverload recommends in [her or his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5792208/575530) mentions that "only the Account Owner can reassign a subscription’s Service Administrator" but does not go on to explain how that is done.

Here is the (current at 17/08/15) process, the **service administrator**:

1. signs in to https://portal.azure.com/
2. goes to the billing blade;

[image: Azure portal screenshot]

3. selects the service to change;

[image: Azure portal screenshot]

4. scrolls down and clicks the 'properties' tile;

[image: Azure portal screenshot]

5. clicks the edit service admin button;

[image: Azure portal screenshot]

6. enters the email address of the new service administrator; and finally
7. clicks the OK button.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to edit it by going to https://account.windowsazure.com/Subscriptions/ and selecting the subscription, then clicking `Edit Subscription Details` in the right-hand menu.

[image: Edit Subscription Details]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what your purpose for wanting to change it is, but an MS evangelist blogged about the options for changing the subscription billing here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/patrick_butler_monterde/archive/2010/02/10/windows-azure-billing-overview.aspx

As far as directly changing the service administrator to another Live ID, I don't know of a way to do it in the current model.

Comment: when you have 40days free service you cant change your service administrator

Answer (score 0):

when you have 40days free service you cant change your service administrator!

Answer (score 0):

**For Azure Gov Only**

This answer may be helpful for someone having the same problem that I had trying to change the subscription **Service Administrator** under Azure Gov.

If you follow the Microsoft documentation related to this question ([Change the Service Administrator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/classic-administrators#change-the-service-administrator)), when you try to sign in to the **Account Center** you will be redirected to the [Public Account Center](https://account.azure.com/subscriptions) and this error will appear after you sign in with an **Azure Gov Account Administrator**

[image]
*Sorry, we were unable to log you in. Please try again or contact support.*

Instead, you need to sign in to the [Gov Account Center](https://account.windowsazure.us/)

---

**For both Azure (Public and Gov). Follow each example**

Another way to access to either Account Centers is by signing in with your **Account Administrator** to the Azure Portal ([Azure Public Portal](https://portal.azure.com) or [Azure Gov Portal](https://portal.azure.us)) and managing the subscription

1. Go to the "Cost Management + Billing" tab

[image]

2. Select the billing scope in which you have the "Account Administrator" role

Example in Azure Gov
[image]

Example in Azure Public
[image]

3. Click in the "**Manage**" link and you will be redirected to the respective "Account Center"

Example in Azure Gov
[image]

Example in Azure Public
[image]